# Authentication credentials were not provided. Django Rest Framework/JWT and React native iOS

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework, jwt, axios

```
    axios.get(
        url,
        {
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + access_token
            }
        }
    )
```

This is the request currently I'm sending to the server on my react native project. When It runs on Android It works without any problem. But on iOS it Shows `Authentication credentials were not provided`. What's wrong with this. Only it happens when I try to send Bearer token with the request. otherwise, axios works on ios too. Please help me to find out the problem. thank you.

Django Settings Part

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=5),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True
}
```

Comment: can you post the django settings module? most probably it's due to JWT prefix settings?

Comment: I updated the django settings part

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution for this error?? Authentication credentials were not provided

Comment: @PrashantGaikwad The problem was a slash. iOS need trialing slash on post requests. Then only it takes authentication headers. So I put a slash on the end in my url, the problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi default Jwt prefix auth prefix is JWT.

```
 Authorization: "JWT" + access_token
```

or you can change the prefix from settings

```
'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'Bearer',
```

https://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/

Comment: I'm using djangorestframework-simplejwt==3.2.3 for web token. 2nd thing is this API works without any problem when I run the same exact code in the android application and on Postman.